# Fullpage.js & iScroll dynamic content height refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, iscroll

When using the scrollOverflow:true option in fullpage.js, is it possible to manually call refresh() on the iscroll objects after content height changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, just use the `reBuild` method of fullpage.js.

From [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#rebuild):

> **reBuild**
>
> Updates the DOM structure to fit the new window size or its contents. Ideal to use in combination with AJAX calls or external changes in the DOM structure of the site.
>
> $.fn.fullpage.reBuild();

Comment: This does not refresh the nested iscroll object.

Comment: @aks. of course it does... and that's why the question was accepted.